# Does MVC3 web.config allow authentication over individual Controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, web-config

I have seen such as

```
<location path="~/SomeController">
   <system.web>
     <authorization>
       <allow users="?"/>
     </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

I placed this section after the   section where it has the  with authentication. This doesn't seem to work. It still asks for log in.

Am I missing something? I'm really new to this so I apologize if this is very rudimentary stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really shouldn't be using the web.config to control the authentication of your application.

Use the `Authorize` attribute on the controllers you want to secure, and leave it off the ones you don't.

See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2010/08/24/securing-your-mvc-application.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for the answer. I was just reading about that, to use [Authorize(Roles.... and something along those lines. I wish we designed using that paradigm but the pages in this MVC3 project is using a master page from a regular Asp.Net project hence we have the authentication done through the web.config. Can you recommend me something that I can in this situation? Is there such thing as [Authorise(Roles = "*")] ? Haha Thank you so much!

Comment: If you protect the controller whocares about the master page since it requires your view no? You can use both but all MVC code should use the authorize attribute

Comment: @Adam Thanks for the response. So there is no configuration required in the web.config file for me to use the Authorize attribute? Would following this article be the way I should set this up? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx

Comment: What I'm stumped on non of the controllers in our projects (whether it's wrong or not.. I'll bring this up to other developers) have that attribute but we still need to login through the login page because of the web.config's setting. I apologize for the slowness but want to understand this as clear as possible. Thank you so much

Comment: It's possible this was setup as a global filter so it applies to every controller. Check your global.Asas.cs. It's also possible whatever is setup now in your web.config is causing the login redirect based on auth settings. It generally isn't reco

Comment: Nothing in the global filter. Ah.. Not sure if this has anything to do with it but I found "defaultUrl='~/ApplicationName'" in one of the <forms> attribute. And since all our controller's url is ~/ApplicationName/Controller(s) do you think that is causing the redirect to the loginurl? Well... I tried to get rid of that attribute but still tells me to log in.. hmmm

Comment: It's possible this was setup as a global filter so it applies to every controller. Check your global.Asas.cs. It's also possible whatever is setup now in your web.config is causing the login redirect based on auth settings. It generally isn't recommended though to use web config because different urls can bring you the same controller if you have routes setup for it plus urls can change so it's easier to secure the code not the URL

Comment: Try <allow users="*"/> any change?

Comment: !!!!! I was going to ask the same thing, if having <deny users="?" /> would make a difference and now it's allowing me to go to the page! And I just had to add [Authorize(Roles="SuperUser, User...")] on the controller it needs the authentication and I can also login to that page as well. Once I'm logged in, would I need any other part of my controllers to add the attribute? Or should I simply add the Authorize attribute in the base controller and add the [AllowAnonymous] attribute in the controller that doesn't require authentication? In any case.. I THANK YOU VERY MUCH :D

Comment: ya, just use AllowAnonymouse where you need it and all should be good!

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can do your authentication on your controllers in the controller itself.

You can set up authentication on a method:

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
 public ActionResult Index()
 { .... }
```

Or you can set it up on the controller itself:

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, SuperUser")]
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {  ... }
```

Hope this helps you some.

Comment: Yea, I was reading about this too, as well. Thank you very much for the response. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to change the `?` to a `*`?  Also, be sure you are changing the root level web.config file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t.aspx

Comment: I tried changing those two characters and let me make sure I did it in the root web.config. Thank you!